# Heroku does not working perfectly for the rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using rails 6 to deploy the code to heroku successfully but the public/packs does not deploy.it has the responsible for the add tag option in post form page.

Application.js

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import "bootstrap"



require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


require('./nested-forms/addFields')

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it to remove the public\packs files in .gitignore